# Need only parent domain from a URL in dnsmasq.log file

Tags: shell, awk, dnsmasq

I want to fetch website names visited by connected LAN clients from dnsmasq.log file. So far i have been able to get this done.

```
cat /tmp/dnsmasq.log | grep query | egrep -v 'AAA|SRV|PTR' |  awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3","$8","$6}'
```

> May 29 12:00:17,127.0.0.1,ftp.box.com
>
> May 29 12:00:33,10.0.0.41,2.android.pool.ntp.org

I need output as

> May 29 12:00:17,127.0.0.1,box.com
>
> May 29 12:00:33,10.0.0.41,ntp.org

I need just the parent domain name in the output. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.Considering that you need last 2 elements of your url.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($NF,array,".");$NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                               ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                         ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
}
{
  num=split($NF,array,".")           ##Splitting last field and metioning . as separator.
  $NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]      ##Setting last column value as 2nd last element DOT and last element of array here.
}
1                                    ##1 will print lines here.
'  Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 for quick response. Command is not giving desired output,                                                                               root@OpenWrt:~/scripts# grep "query" /tmp/dnsmasq.log | egrep -v 'AAA|SRV|PTR' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($6,array,".");$6=array[num-1]"."array[num];print $1"
"$2" "$3,$8,$6}'
May 29 13:15:02 dnsmasq[25328]: query[A] www.google.com from 127.0.0.1  ,,.
May 29 13:15:43 dnsmasq[25328]: query[A] presence.teams.microsoft.com from 10.0.0.2  ,,.
May 29 13:15:51 dnsmasq[25328]: query[A] hclo365-my.sharepoint.com from 10.0.0.35  ,,.

Comment: @nbuser, You should really post sample of `/tmp/dnsmasq.log` since you are asking about joining this one with your command then try something like `cat /tmp/dnsmasq.log | grep query | egrep -v 'AAA|SRV|PTR' |  awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3","$8","$6}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($NF,array,".");$NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]} 1'` But trust  me this is NOT efficient at all, you could test it but better you could let your samples know with all details in your question to make it in one single `awk`, which is capable of doing it single handed.

Comment: @nbuser, in your question please not in comments.

Comment: Thanks this command worked. cat /tmp/dnsmasq.log | grep query | egrep -v 'AAA|SRV|PTR' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3","$8","$6}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {num=split($NF,array,".");$NF=array[num-1]"."array[num]} 1'

Comment: I am sure there must be a better way to handle it but for now it is solving my problem. Thanks once again for your help and have marked your answer as solution.